# C++ how can I stop the exe from closing after finish?

Tags: c++, exe

I can see the output when I use the compiler but when I use the exe separately, it closes after finishing, so I can't see the output. What can I do to make the exe stay open?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    setlocale (LC_ALL,"hun");
    cout<<"b: ";
    double b,a,c,x1,x2,valami,gyokalattvalami,minusb,kettoa;
    cin>>b;
    cout<<"a: ";
    cin>>a;
    cout<<"c: ";
    cin>>c;
    valami=pow(b,2)-4*a*c;
    //cout<<valami <<endl;
    gyokalattvalami=pow(valami,0.5);
    //cout<<gyokalattvalami;
    minusb=b-b*2;
    //cout<<minusb;
    kettoa=2*a;
    //cout<<kettoa;
    x1=(minusb+gyokalattvalami)/kettoa;
    x2=(minusb-gyokalattvalami)/kettoa;
    system("CLS");
    cout<<"X1=" <<x1 <<endl;
    cout<<"X2=" <<x2;
}
```

Comment: How are you running the exe?  Are you running it from the command prompt or double clicking on it?

Comment: do a character input as the final statement so that the program will sit waiting for input with the window displaying.

Comment: You have two options: 1. Run from the command line. 2. Add another `cin` statement at the end which causes the code to wait for more input until the user types more input.

Comment: Use `system("pause")` or `std::cin.get()`;

Comment: @Raindrop7 Thanks, that's just what I was looking for.